# Qué hace el operador "^" en indices de arrays en NumPy

Tags: python, array, numpy, matriz, operador

He estado investigando unos operadores que se usan en el indice de array de NumPy, pero hay un operador que aun no lo entiendo del todo, es el signo diacrítico o circunflejo (^)

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.array([10,6,8,2,9,4,7,5,12,9])
print(numbers)
print(numbers[(numbers<9)^2])
print(numbers[(numbers<9)^3])
```

¿Qué hace especificamente este operador?

Comment: ¿Es posible que sea la operación de potencia?

Answer (score 1):

El operador "^" en Python (y por tanto en NumPy) es el operador XOR, conocida como disyunción exclusiva o "or" exclusivo. Es una operacion a nivel de bits. Se evalúa como verdadera cuando solo uno de los operandos es verdadero:

```
╔═══╦═══╦═════╗
║ A ║ B ║ A^B ║
╠═══╬═══╬═════╣
║ 0 ║ 0 ║  0  ║
╠═══╬═══╬═════╣
║ 1 ║ 0 ║  1  ║
╠═══╬═══╬═════╣
║ 0 ║ 1 ║  1  ║
╠═══╬═══╬═════╣
║ 1 ║ 1 ║  0  ║
╚═══╩═══╩═════╝
```

La única diferencia en el caso de NumPy es que vectoriza la operación, lo mismo que hace con el resto de operaciones.

Como es una operación a nivel de bits, si se aplica sobre enteros la operación se realiza sobre la representación binaria de los enteros bit a bit, por ejemplo `17 ^ 13`:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ Decimal ║      Binario      ║
╠═════════╬═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╣
║    17   ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║
╠═════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║    13   ║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║
╠═════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ 17 ^ 13 ║ 1 ║ 1 ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 
╚═════════╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

Lo que da como resultado 28 (11100 en binario).

Teniendo esto claro, veamos tu ejemplo:

```
numbers[(numbers<9)^3])

╔═══════════════════════════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║              numbers              ║ 10      ║ 6       ║ 8       ║ 2       ║ 9       ║ 4       ║ 7       ║ 5       ║ 12      ║ 9       ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ numbers < 9 (0 = False, 1 = True) ║ 0       ║ 1       ║ 1       ║ 1       ║ 0       ║ 1       ║ 1       ║ 1       ║ 0       ║ 0       ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║         (numbers < 9) ^ 3         ║ 0^11=11 ║ 1^11=10 ║ 1^11=10 ║ 1^11=10 ║ 0^11=11 ║ 1^11=10 ║ 1^11=10 ║ 1^11=10 ║ 0^11=11 ║ 0^11=11 ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║        [(numbers < 9) ^ 3]        ║ 3       ║ 2       ║ 2       ║ 2       ║ 3       ║ 2       ║ 2       ║ 2       ║ 3       ║ 3       ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║     numbers[(numbers < 9) ^ 3]    ║ 2       ║ 8       ║ 8       ║ 8       ║ 2       ║ 8       ║ 8       ║ 8       ║ 2       ║ 2       ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

Para aclarar la tabla, tomemos el segundo numero de tu array, el 6:

- `6 < 9` es `True`, es decir `1`.
- `1 ^ 3` es `01 ^ 11` (3 es 11 en binario) y `01 ^ 11 = 10`
- `10` en binario es `2` en decimal.
- `numbers[2]` es 8

Comment: Perfecto doc, esta bien explicado. Gracias.